# Why does ordering matter in type hinting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, python-typing

Why is this ok

```
class Ship:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

class Fleet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ships = []

    def add_ship(self, ship: Ship):
        self.ships.append(ship)
```

But this is not?

```
class Fleet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ships = []

    def add_ship(self, ship: Ship):
        self.ships.append(ship)

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
```

I know that you cannot have circular references in importing. However, this is not an import thing: both of these are in the same file. In both cases the definition of Ship is made, but it seems as though if Fleet is defined first it can't find the definition of Ship. This is *not* true if I used `isinstance` to check the type.

```
def add_ship(self, ship):
    if isinstance(ship, Ship): # works fine
        self.ships.append(ship)
```

However, that does not allow my IDE (PyCharm) to see the definition and autocomplete syntax.

In fact, the following design pattern seems to work fine

```
class Fleet:

    def __init__(self):
        self.ships = []

    def add_ship(self, ship):
        if isinstance(ship, Ship):
            self.ships.append(ship)

class Ship:

    def __init__(self, parent):
        if isinstance(parent, Fleet):
            self.parent = parent
```

But, again, does not allow for my IDE to figure out the types. This is Python 3.6.5/Anaconda/Windows 10.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`def add_ship(self, ship: Ship):` is evaluated at **definition time**. At that time `Ship` is not defined yet.

`if isinstance(ship, Ship):` is evaluated only when `add_ship` is called. This will (hopefully) be only after `Ship` had been defined.

[PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) (implemented in Python 3.7 and above) solves this by making the type annotations evaluation lazy.

If you upgrade, you can add `from __future__ import annotations`  to the top of the file and that example will work.

This will be fully implemented in Python 4.0, meaning `from __future__ import annotations` will not be needed.

**Pre Python 3.7 solution**

If you can't or don't want to upgrade to Python >= 3.7 you can use a string-literal annotation (which is also mentioned in the PEP I linked to):

```
def add_ship(self, ship: 'Ship'):
```

Comment: The second method of using string literals looks more solid, but does it have any downsides we should be aware of?

Comment: Also, if you need to accept multiple types for a parameter (i.e. Ship and Ferry), what's the syntax for that when using the string-literal annotation method?